# How do you remove hyperlink error stripes in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea, jira

Is there a way to remove the hyperlink error stripes for the Atlassian connector in IDEA?

For example, if I include a ticket number in a comment (e.g. TR-12345), IDEA automatically detects that this is a reference to a JIRA ticket and turns this comment into a link to the ticket in the relevant project. I like this feature. What I don't like is that it also adds a blue error stripe to the marker bar (the sidebar on the right). Is there a way to remove the error stripe without getting rid of the nice linking functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature is most likely provided by the Atlassian plug-in that you've installed for IDEA as I don't see such functionality by default.

If the plug-in is implemented properly, it should provide its own settings for `Settings` | `Editor` | `Colors & Fonts`. For example in the `General` group there is a setting for `TODO defaults` that has `Error Stripe Mark` option enabled.

You should find the similar setting provided by the plug-in and disable the `Error Stripe Mark` option.

Note that there is already `Hyperlink` element in the `General` group, but it has `Error Stripe Mark` disabled by default.

Comment: If that's the case, then I guess the plug-in isn't implemented properly...I submitted a feature request.